# Forbid divs to wrap around other divs?

Tags: css

Is there a way to forbid div wrap other div here  http://jsfiddle.net/MaL5k/1/ ?
But without repeating size of left div like done here http://jsfiddle.net/MaL5k/2/

It's seems obvios there should be an option to forbid div content wrap other div content and just act as it a square block.

Comment: Already found a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/MaL5k/7/

Comment: Should I remove question or leave it?

Comment: You may remove it if you want to, I doubt anybody has invested much effort into this question yet. Your solution is sound.

Comment: @Purmou Can't accept my own answer. 2 days have to pass.

Comment: @grisevg: Then wait two days, heh. I've done the same a couple times.

Comment: I am interested in why that solution works.  I wouldn't have guessed that `overflow:hidden` would help align text...

Comment: @mwcz: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809079/two-divs-side-by-side-one-100-width-others-width-depended-on-content/6809143#6809143

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Already found a solution: using overflow:hidden;  http://jsfiddle.net/MaL5k/7/

EDIT:
Doesn't work in IE6... but who cares about it anymore (=

Comment: Then wait 2 days :) or increase your rep